# To check factorization in axiom in cofibration category, it suffices to check factorization of codiagonal map.

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

Say we have category $C$ with class of morphisms weak equivalence and cofibration. And say we have that (Acylic) cofibrations are closed under pushouts, composition. And that initial object is in $C$ and every object is cofibrant and isomorphism are weak equivalences and weak equivalences satisfy 2-out-of-6.

With this, to check that every map can be factored as cofibration followed by weak equivalence, it is a fact that it suffices to check the factorization for the codiagonal map $X \sqcup X \to X$.

I'm looking for the proof of this fact.

Thanks!

Comment: The dual statement is a standard fact about categories of fibrant objects. You can find the proof in e.g. Ken Brown's original paper (_Abstract homotopy theory and generalized sheaf cohomology_).